# How to do #include Macro and take macro value from commandline in C++

Tags: c++

```
#define MACRO 

int main () {

#include MACRO
}
```

Pseudo Code is present above.
MACRO value I am tsking from commandline like

```
g++ -DMACRO="x.h"
```

Error is showing

> ```
> #include expects "FILENAME" or <FILENAME>
> ```

Comment: You do not need to define the macro, as this is what the `-DMACRO=...` does.

Comment: The solution depends on what shell you're using (under unix flavours) or command line processor (e.g CMD under windows).   Different command line processors handle double quotes differently and may not pass the double quote (`"`) characters on the command line unless they are escaped in some way.

Comment: The gcc preprocessor also has an [`-include file` option](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.2.0/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options) to add additional includes to the compiled files.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is most likely that your command environment removes the double-quotes in the argument, you need to escape the quotes:

```
$ g++ -DMACRO=\"x.h\"
```

Comment: Also, he probably shouldn't `#define MACRO` in compilation unit.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `#define MACRO`, 
this clashes with your definition of `MACRO` in the command line arguments.